# Grails button to create entity passing parameters

Tags: grails, button, hyperlink, gsp

I have two entities: Event and Person.

I have both gsp pages that allows me to create events and persons. In Event page, I have the possibility to select an existing person, or I can insert name, surname and phone number.

I would have a button that, if that three fields are filled, allows me to jump to create page of Person, with that three fields filled with data inserted in Event page.

I've tried with  tag as follows:

```
<g:link controller="patient" action="create" 
params="[name: eventInstance.patientName, surname: eventInstance.patientSurname, 
phone_1: eventInstance.phoneNumber]">link</g:link>
```

but in this way parameters are empty.

Any suggestion?

EDIT:
I've tried the following:

```
<g:actionSubmit value="createPatient" action="createPatient"></g:actionSubmit>
```

and the action is:

```
def createPatient()
{
    def eventInstance = new Event(params)
    println("params are "+ params)

    redirect(controller: "patient", action: "create", params: [name: "name", surname:
    "surname", phone_1: "025-84569"] )
}
```

In this way, the Create action is performed and I see the gsp page with form prefilled with parameter passed. The fact is that `params` has not the values that I want to pass to create.gsp (values needed are patientName, patientSurname and phoneNumber). Infact, the `println()` shows me:

```
params are [_action_createPatient:createPatient, recurInterval:1, recurCount:,
recurType:DAILY, endTime:, recurEndOption:never, recurUntil:, startTime:, title:, 
patient_textField:, healthService.id:1, healthService:[id:1], patientName:, 
phoneNumber:, description:, _recurDaysOfWeek:[, , , , , , ], patientSurname:, 
patient_id:, action:save, controller:event]
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? What is your current approach? This seems to be a broad question, take a look at Grails `CRUD` and [scaffolding](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html), try couple appraoches. If you still had problem, post your errors and your approach for further assistant.

Comment: I've updated my question...I hope it is more clear now...